# modifying system call in Linux kernel and recompiling in a virtual machine (not a module)

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel, system-calls

I am trying to modify the sys_write system call in the Linux kernel. I have researched and found the source code online, but I don't know how to access the source code in my virtual machine so that I can start changing it. I have looked everywhere in the file system, but all I can find are header files and makefiles. I am thinking that they made the .c files invisible from within the OS for a reason. Does anyone know how I can get to them, or do I have to modify source I download from the internet and recompile from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: download and build Linux Kernel. In internet there is so many tutorials about that. After that you can try to write own System Call but for every new system call you need to rebuild a kernel.